# android drawerLayout multiple choice

Tags: android, drawerlayout, multiple-choice

I want to have a sliding drawer using drawerlayout, but I want to be able to choose multiple options from within the drawer.

I'm thinking of using it to aid with filtering of a list of items. The filter will be a new activity that appears on top of the list page, and then each option on the left e.g. price, size, make etc, will open the slide draw on the right.

Is it possible? Or will the drawerlayout always close after one selection?

Thanks

Russ

Comment: Post code of what you have so far?

Comment: I haven't really written code. I've copied the example at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html and then tried adding android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" to the listview but it doesn't stay open after selecting the first option.

I think I may have to add functionality to keep the drawer open to allow the extra clicks.